# i can't view a winform in visual studio visualy

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I was watching a Winforms tutorial and when I clicked on the form before running it told me "this item does not support previewing" and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Visual Studio2019 16.7.5 for testing. It works fine for me.

You could create other applications (such as console application) to see if the same problem exists.

I recommend you to update to the most recent release of Visual Studio 2019 so that you always get the latest features, fixes, and improvements.

[Update Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)